# Inverse function of sum of coth and tanh terms

Tags: inverse, hyperbolic-functions

In a [publication](https://scholar.google.com/scholar_lookup?doi=10.1016/0378-3812%2881%2985002-9) I found an equation (eq. 11of the linked publication) of the form

$$c_p = B
+ C \left( \frac{D/T}{\sinh(D/T)} \right)^2 
+ E \left( \frac{F/T}{\cosh(F/T)} \right)^2$$

$T$ is the temperature, so it is always larger than zero, $c_p$ is the heat capacity, it is also larger than zero and it is monotonically increasing iwth $T$.
The parameters $B \dots F$ have a physical meaning, but here they are just fitted to measured data. The publication includes a table with recommended constant values for the parameters.

The equation can be integrated to yield enthalpy $H$ (eq. 12 of the linked publication)

$$H = BT 
+ CT \left( \frac{D}{T} \right) \coth\left( \frac{D}{T} \right)
- ET \left( \frac{F}{T} \right) \tanh\left( \frac{F}{T} \right)
+ A$$

$T$ cancels out, so that the equation becomes

$$H = BT 
+ CD \coth\left( \frac{D}{T} \right)
- EF \tanh\left( \frac{F}{T} \right)
+ A$$

Using $x=1/T$ then gives

$$H = B/x 
+ CD \coth\left( Dx \right)
- EF \tanh\left( Fx \right)
+ A$$

For my application, I know the value of $H$  and have to iteratively find the corresponding value of $x$. If possible, it should be nicer to invert the function symbolically once and have an expression $x=x \left( H \right)$ that can be evaluated directly. Does the shown equation have an inverse function? As a unexperienced user I was not able to find an inverse function using Sympy or Mathematica.

If an exact inverse does not exist, I would as well be interested in a new parametric equation that can be fitted to measured/calculated data.

Comment: I'd say you can't solve for $x$ algebraically because it is within a trig function *and* outside of the trig functions as well.  Using complex extensions should get you into an unsolvable scenario where we can't solve for $x$ in the similar equation $e^{ax}+e^{bx}+x=y$.

Comment: @SimpleArt The question has been updated to correspond more closely to the referenced publication, $x$ and $y$ are no longer used.

Comment: I still don't think this is possible, as far as an "exact inverse"

Comment: Shouldn't it be $$H = BT 
+ CT \left( \frac{D}{T} \right) \coth\left( \frac{D}{T} \right)
- ET \left( \frac{F}{T} \right) \tanh\left( \frac{\color{blue}{F}}{T} \right)
+ A$$?

Comment: @YuriyS Yes, thanks, I will update the question also.

Comment: If you have a Ti-84, instead of trying to find an inverse, you can program in newtons method to find T. I suspect inverting it wouldn't give you a "much nicer" solution.

Comment: ..assuming a closed inverse even exists.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla Equation 11 of the [linked paper](https://scholar.google.com/scholar_lookup?doi=10.1016/0378-3812%2881%2985002-9) is (part of) an [equation of state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_state#Helmholtz_Function_form), descibed the properties of fluids. During dynamic simulation of e.g. a power plant the equation will be evaluated millions of times. Fluid properties calculations consume 50-95% of CPU time for the simulation. Using Newton and similar methods is how it is done today, but inverting the equations once might speed up things.

Comment: Updated the question to show simplified eq 12 (T cancels out)